# Getting "process cannot access file" error when deleting files after sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, file-io, visual-studio-2005

I am getting error as mentioned below:

**The process cannot access file "E:\TempPDFs\Sample.pdf" because it is being used by another process**

I happen to send the pdf from email and after email is sent i need to delete the Sample.pdf file. The code that i have written doesn't work

```
FileInfo DeleteFileInfo = new FileInfo(directoryPath + "\\" + filename + ".pdf");
                            if (DeleteFileInfo.Exists)
                                File.Delete(directoryPath + "\\" + filename + ".pdf");
```

here directorypath is E:\TempPDFs, filename is Sample

**UPDATED:**

```
public static void SendMail(string fromAddress, string[] toAddress, string[] ccAddress, string[] bccAddress, string subject, string messageBody, bool isBodyHtml, ArrayList attachments, string host, string username, string pwd, string port)
    {

        {
            try
            {
                if (isBodyHtml && !htmlTaxExpression.IsMatch(messageBody))
                    isBodyHtml = false;
                // Create the mail message
                MailMessage objMailMsg;
                objMailMsg = new MailMessage();
                if (toAddress != null)
                {
                    foreach (string toAddr in toAddress)
                        objMailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddr));
                }
                if (ccAddress != null)
                {
                    foreach (string ccAddr in ccAddress)
                        objMailMsg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccAddr));
                }
                if (bccAddress != null)
                {
                    foreach (string bccAddr in bccAddress)
                        objMailMsg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bccAddr));
                }

                if (fromAddress != null && fromAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    //if (fromAddress != null && fromName.trim().length > 0)
                    //    objMailMsg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress, fromName);
                    //else
                    objMailMsg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
                }

                objMailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                objMailMsg.Subject = subject;
                objMailMsg.Body = messageBody;
                objMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;

                if (attachments != null)
                {
                    foreach (string fileName in attachments)
                    {
                        if (fileName.Trim().Length > 0 && File.Exists(fileName))
                            objMailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileName));
                    }
                }

                //prepare to send mail via SMTP transport
                SmtpClient objSMTPClient = new SmtpClient();

                if (objSMTPClient.Credentials != null)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    objSMTPClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd);
                    objSMTPClient.Host = host;
                    objSMTPClient.Port = Int16.Parse(port);
                    //objSMTPClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    objSMTPClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
                    //objSMTPClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    //objSMTPClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                }
                //objSMTPClient.Host = stmpservername;
                //objSMTPClient.Credentials
                //System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup mMailsettings = null;
                //string mailHost = mMailsettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
                try
                {
                    objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg);
                }
                catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
                {
                    if (smtpEx.Message.Contains("secure connection"))
                    {
                        objSMTPClient.EnableSsl = true;
                        objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

let me know if any query

Thanks!

Comment: FYI,The Sample.pdf is not open when i am getting this error.

Comment: Does your SMTP service have the file open for read (sending the mail simultaneously with your delete)?

Comment: Can you provide the mail sending code? Are you creating PDF dynamically?

Comment: If you use SmtpClient to send the file, you must Dispose the object (using/Dispose).

Comment: @qor72: I dont know that whether the SMTP service setting done as if it has file open, but i guess it is not being deleted as the mail is still being sent.

Comment: @Anuraj: I am creating pdf via c# code. I can't send the code as it exceeds the maximum limit of sending any comments

Comment: @Romil Nagrani: Hope you are disposing the Stream objects properly which is used for creating PDF file. Use a using keyword.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can we see a code that is responsible for sending a PDF file via e-mail? Your problem might be caused by not released memory stream. If you're using an [Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) class then you should do like the following:

```
using (Attachment data = new Attachment("document.pdf",  MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet))
{
    // 1. Adding attachment to the e-mail message
    // 2. Sending out the e-mail message
}
```

The `using` statement will ensure that the [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144637.aspx) method is called when the object gets out of the scope.

**UPDATE**

After calling the [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) method make a call to [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w54a951.aspx) of your mail message object:

```
objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg);
objMailMsg.Dispose();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You can see a code but as i said before, it exceeds the maximum limit of any comments

Comment: @Romil: Don't post it as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

or better yet if the object implements IDisposable just write like this

```
((IDisposable)objSMTPClient).Dispose();
```